# Why my drop down list did not working C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Sunday");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Monday");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Tuesday");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Wednesday");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Thursday");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Friday");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Saturday");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact("Sunday");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string var;
            var = comboBox1.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(var);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code but when i try to run it, its fine but my drop down list did not show any values. I still new in this C# language, forgive me if i did not realized any mistake in the code. Somebody, please help and explain to me what is the error and the solution for it. I really need it. Much appreciate.

Comment: Please place your code in your question so that it's possible to copy and paste it. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Avoid posting sample code as image, other users may not able to see image due to their network firewall or other unexpected causes. Paste your sample code in question body (see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto +1 for that site. That's gone straight into my favourites :)

Comment: @Demi I have _manually typed out_ your `Form1_Load()` code into my own form load code and it works just fine. Since I now have the code I've added it.

Comment: You most likely don't have the load event wired up.  Use the OnLoad override instead.

Comment: Your code should work properly but maybe the events are not set up correctly. You need to recheck or use Constructor

Comment: what is thats means sir?

Comment: When you double-click on a form to edit the "On Load" event, Visual Studio does some work for you that ties your code (shown above) to the "Form.Load" event of Form1. That code doesn't appear to be working in your case. I'd _strongly_ recommend you make a cop of the code above, and start again. It's possible to fix where you are but explaining it is not very easy, especially with someone so new to the topic. Try from fresh, get it working.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need to load the items in the "form load" event, you can do so in `Form1()` itself after `InitializeComponent()`, and secondly you could try using List and ItemsSource:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<string> items = new List<string> { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
    comboBox1.ItemsSource = items;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;       //since you know "Sunday" is at index 0
}
```

EDIT: Since as John comments, the code you provided already works, my answer will remain a suggestion to shorten & simplify your code.

Comment: While these are good points, the code he has already shown works just fine.

Comment: Thank you sir. But when i try to run, it has an error saying that i did not have any extension method to comboBox1.ItemSource= items; What is that means? How can i resolved it?

Comment: @demi Are you sure you used `comboBox1.ItemsSource= items;` and not `comboBox1.ItemSource= items;` as the typo in your comment suggests (note the extra 's' after 'Item')?